# primefaces separate javascript from xhtml

Tags: javascript, primefaces, unobtrusive-javascript

How do I separate the HTML from the CSS from the JS in a page made using primefaces?
I don't have anything made yet and I'm trying to adapt to primefaces.

Note: I already know how to work with jsp and I have been working with the HTML5 + CSS3 + HTML5's DOM spec (with the help of jQuery, occasionally).

For example:

Consider I have a page with checkboxes. [This one is a good example about it](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectBooleanCheckbox.jsf).

According to the example, I have to write the js and CSS associated to it inside the XML related to created those custom made HTML + CSS + JS checkboxes (just not to say that that is broken, per se).

When I try to find how to separate all parts such that the XML has absolutely no js inside, there's no documentation for it.

Comment: Can you put an example from your code?

Comment: @RafaHernández I haven't made anything using primefaces (or jsf) yet. I'm trying to understand how it works (while keeping it organized to me) in order to do something using it.

Comment: this is a good page for understand JSF  with examples
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

"In JSF 2.0, all your web resources files like css, images or JavaScript, should put in “resources” folder, under the root of your web application (same folder level with “WEB-INF“).

The sub-folder under “resources” folder is consider as “library” or “project theme“, later you can reference those “resources” with library attribute. This new JSF resources management mechanism is really useful, it allow developer to change the web resources easily by “theme/library” or “versioning”. " Source [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

***See more:***

- [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)
- [Resource Ordering In PrimeFaces](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/resource-ordering-in-primefaces/)
- [How To Include JavaScript File In JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-jsf/)
- [How To Include Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) In JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/)
- [JSF 2 Templating With Facelets Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thamn... So many stuff... To think HTML and the DOM was already a large library... This just overflows... So many rules and names and gymmicks... Thanks... It will take a while before I even understand what exactly is a component too (I already have some ideas).

Comment: Specially because I'm used to make the input form the user in the same place as the output (forms and some ajax submitted to the same page). And then doing everything with a nice fine grain control; while also using templates based on code I had made in the past that is improved as time passes. There's nothing faster and easier to work with than my own code. PHP is also quite nice as it feels like a framework that does just enough (even with its historical problems)

Comment: Even though you have shown me a lot and I have tried using those resources to answer my question... It still does not actually solve it. I'm interested in separating at 100% level the javascript code from the xhtml file. I'll be forced to tolerate tags like <p:ajax> (sounds like I have no real choice) but how about the rest? Is the concept of jsf to mix all js + CSS + HTML in a single place in a spaggetti-codish thing? Is it meant for us to go back to HTML3-like with the ugly on* attributes?

Comment: I can't see where's the mixing you are talking about, I don't consider <p:ajax> to a case of mixing. I think you're talking about the outcome of the html...

Comment: I'm thinking about both, actually. The outcome and the one I write for jsf to parse